# docker container with own mysql or global docker mysql

Tags: mysql, docker

We are using docker a lot with our production. Current solution is to use docker with docker-compose setting like this:

```
   version: '2'
    services:
        service:
            build:
                context: .
                dockerfile: Dockerfile
            expose:
            - 3000
            links:
            - mysql
            environment:
            - DB_HOST=mysql
            - DB_DATABASE=test
            - DB_PORT=3306
            - DB_PASSWORD=test
            - DB_USER=test
        mysql:
            image: mysql:5.7
            environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
            - MYSQL_USER=test
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
            restart: always
            volumes:
```

Question is should we use container based mysql like we use? Or should we make an global msyql docker container and link the all containers to that mysql?

What are the best practices for concerning memory and cpu consumption?

Comment: ...or use a non-Docker MySQL, or use a database somewhere else entirely that someone else maintains (maybe something cloud-hosted like Amazon’s RDS).  All of these are valid options.

Comment: is there some best practises for docker environment. How about cpu and memory cases? Does container based mysql use more memory or cpu?